# Linux Mint: invisible white-on-white menu items

Tags: linux, linux-mint, netbeans, gtk

Linux Mint 14 Nadia (and possibly older versions as well) displays the text of some menu items in the same colour as the menu background, rendering the menu item impossible to read, unless hovered over. Netbeans is one such application where this is a problem.

Example of this invisible menu item problem:

[image]

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be fixed by the Mint devs [1]. The problem lies in the Mint-X GTK theme, but can be fixed quite easily. Open the following file:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Styles/menu.rc`

Find the following line (around line 14):

`fg[ACTIVE] = @selected_fg_color`

and replace it with the following:

`fg[ACTIVE] = @menu_fg_color`

Save the file. The hidden menu items should now display correctly. Note that you may need to manually trigger a reload of the theme. The easiest way to to this is to log off and log back on again.

[1] I've submitted the fix to the bug tracker. The answer here on SU serves to help the people affected by this problem until the patch makes its way into Mint.

Comment: Thanks; that's really been bugging me!  I think the more general advice is that `fg[ACTIVE]` needs to match `fg[NORMAL]`; so I changed `@bg_color` to `@fg_color` on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela.